# AngularJS : Access ng-repeat $index inside directive link function to access item in collection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've run into a wall and none of the documentation is helping thus far.  I'm trying to create a directive that replaces an element with an iframe pointed to an external resource and each item in my array has a link to its own resource.

My data in the **controller** looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "title"     :   "Launch",
        "name"      :   "Barbaz",   
        "resource"  :   $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://external.domain:14168/Bar/Baz")
    },
    {
        "title"     :   "Launch",
        "name"      :   "Foobar",
        "resource"  :   $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://external.domain:14168/Foo/Bar")                                                 
    }
];
```

My **html** looks like this:

```
<stuffs element="thing in things">
    <iframe ng-src="{{thing.resource}}" />
</stuffs>
```

My **directive** looks like this:

```
stuffsModule.directive('stuffs', function ($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        transclude: 'element',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        template: [
            '<ul>',
                '<li>',
                    '<iframe />',
                '</li>',
            '</ul>'
        ].join(''),

        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            var rpt = document.createAttribute('ng-repeat');
            rpt.value = tAttrs.element;
            tElement[0].children[0].attributes.setNamedItem(rpt);


            return function (scope, element, attr){ 
                var rhs = attr.element.split(' in ')[1];
                scope.facilities = $parse(rhs)(scope);
                var src = document.createAttribute('ng-src');
                src.value = scope.things[scope.$parent.$index].resource; //<= Blows Up

                element[0].children[0].children[0].attributes.setNamedItem(src);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

No matter what I do, scope.$parent.$index evaluates to *undefined*.

Can anyone see any reason why I don't have access to $index in the linker function? Shouldn't it have already been wired up for me by the ng-repeat directive that I added in the compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not exactly answer for your question but please see here I hope that will help you http://jsbin.com/tevuqe/1/edit

```
app.directive('stuffs', function ($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        transclude: 'element',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        template: [
            '<ul>',
                '<li>',
                   '<p>{{thing.resource}}</p>',
                    '<iframe ng-src="{{thing.resource}}" />',
                '</li>',
            '</ul>'
        ].join(''),

        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            var rpt = document.createAttribute('ng-repeat');
            rpt.value = tAttrs.element;
          console.log(tAttrs.element);
            tElement[0].children[0].attributes.setNamedItem(rpt);



        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Actually, that is *exactly* what I wanted. I had tried to set ng-src through the template in a prior go around, but angular was not interpolating thing.resource. It was just emitting <iframe ng-src />

I see your JSBin working in the browser, but when I adapt it to my project, I still see the iframe in the template without its ng-src being set to {{thing.resource}}.  Have you ever seen that happen before?

Comment: Note that I now have your sample working.  I had refreshed my source control and the "resource" property was improperly named on my model. I had fixed it prior but didn't put 2 and 2 together that that was the reason the template approach would not work. I was tunnel visioned down the compile path.